# How to fix vmlinux.o error and cross-compiling error

Tags: android, linux, kernel, cross-compiling

I am a kind of noob in kernel. First my question is about cross compiling. When i tried to `export CROSS_COMPILE` I got error:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/root/Downloads/android-ndk-r20-beta1/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-eabi-
export ARCH=arm
make clean
/root/Desktop/kek/android_kernel_lge_g3-lineage-16.0/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: /root/Downloads/android-ndk-r20-beta1/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

The second error is `vmlinux` error while compiling.

```
make -no-pie
```

then error

```
ld: cannot find arch/x86/kernel/head_64.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/kernel/head64.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/kernel/head.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/kernel/init_task.o
ld: cannot find init/built-in.o 
make: *** [Makefile:938: vmlinux.o] Error 1  `
```

My kernel is https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_lge_g3 and config is `defconfig`.

Comment: about your first error, what is the output of `ls  -la /root/Downloads/android-ndk-r20-beta1/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/`? and of `file /root/Downloads/android-ndk-r20-beta1/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-eabi-gcc`? I think it is redundant to address the second problem before solving the first as it looks like there is problem in the compiler.

Comment: Hi I am a kind of noob in building kernel. Maybe you will help me I just need to add my belkin wireless adaptor driver in kernel. I want to launch one app but I need this drives. Here is the link on guide https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2338179 . Link to my kernel is higher. Model of my phone is LG g3 vs985. Model of my adaptor is BELKIN FD7 . And Ethernet card model of this adaptor is RTL8150 . Please help me build it for me. My email is lazorykrostyslav@gmail.com .